# Swiftmailer SMTP Hotmail doesn't work

Tags: smtp, pear, swiftmailer, hotmail

I try to send an e-mail with Swiftmailer. But it doesn't  work...
This is what I tried:

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.life.com', 25)
->setUsername('olivier-zwat@hotmail.be')
->setPassword('the correct pasword');
```

I can't find the solution for solving this problem...
*BTW I'm a Dutchman! ;-)

Comment: what errors do you get? "doesn't work" is not a good description.

Comment: The errors I get see here: http://oli4tje.3owl.com/PEAR/Swiftmailer/test.php

Comment: "Service Temporarily Unavailable" is not helpful.

Comment: Sorry, my server is doing some things I don't understand...
So the error starts with: 
"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first "' in /home/u399707880/public_html/PEAR/Swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:386 Stack trace: #0 /home/u399707880/public_html/PEAR/Swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(281): "...

Comment: And goes on with .."Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_assertResponseCode('530 5.7.0 Must ...', Array) #1 /home/u399707880/public_html/PEAR/Swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php(245): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->executeCommand('MAIL FROM: <oli...', Array, Array) #2 /home/u399707880/public_html/PEAR/Swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php(327): "..

Comment: Last part: .."Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->executeCommand('MAIL FROM: <oli...', Array) #3 /home/u399707880/public_html/PEAR/Swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(416): Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->_doMailFromCommand('olivi in /home/u399707880/public_html/PEAR/Swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php on line 386"

Answer (score 1):

> 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

You need to configure SwiftMailer to use a SSL connection via STARTTLS. It is supported since version 4.1.3.

Comment: So I tryed: "$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.live.com', 587, 'starttls')" instead of "$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.live.com', 587)" But now I got another error => 
"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message ""' in /home/u399707880/public_html/PEAR/Swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:386 Stack trace: #0 /home/u399707880/public_html/PEAR/Swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(281): "..

Comment: .."Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_assertResponseCode('', Array) #1 /home/u399707880/public_html/PEAR/Swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php(245): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->executeCommand('RSET??', Array, Array) #2 /home/u399707880/public_html/PEAR/Swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/Esmtp/Auth/PlainAuthenticator.php(47): Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->executeCommand('RSET??', Array) #3 /home/u399707880/public_html/PEAR/Swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/Esmtp/AuthHandler.php(179): "..

Comment: .."Swift_Transport_Esmtp_Auth_PlainAuthenticator->authenticate(Object(Swift_SmtpTransport), 'peeterskenolivi...', 'oli4is1ole') #4 /home/u3997 in /home/u399707880/public_html/PEAR/Swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php on line 386"

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change 'smtp.**life**.com' to 'smtp.**live**.com'.

Comment: So I changed it in this =>


$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.live.com', 587,)
 ->setUsername('myemail@domain.com')
        ->setPassword('******');

The error I get is to long to post it hree... You can see it on my domain: http://oli4tje.3owl.com/PEAR/Swiftmailer/test.php

Greetz

Comment: This is the configuration that works with me:


$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.live.com', 587, 'tls');
$transport->setAuthMode('login');

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the encryption to **tls** as the 3rd parameter:

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.life.com', 25, 'tls')
```

Most probably port should also be set to **587**